# top batch output/width of command field

Tags: top, systemd-unit

`top` truncates the `command` field to fit the width of the terminal line.

How can I maximise the width of that field for capture through a systemd-service? The assumption seems to be that the systemd output line is restricted.

Comment: Here's [an answer I wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718460/531636) a couple of weeks ago about using `top` to capture processes, with pointers on generating wide (long) command fields for the individual processes.

Comment: Why do you want to capture `top` output? That is usually not a good idea since `top` is designed to be used interactively. If you [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is, we should be able to give an alternative approach. Most likely what you need can be done using `ps` instead.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30129/117549

Comment: Though it seems to me that systemd would surely have a better way of getting processes than by scraping `top`?!?